# Access difficulty with ArrayList of panels with buttons

Tags: java, arraylist, actionlistener

my question is: how do I get the object of my CustomPanel, so that I am able to access its fields (because in my real programm I have some more fields in there) and also am able to delete it from my ArrayList?

I don't know how I have to implement an ActionListener in the Class Window, to somehow get the Object in my Arraylist, which containes the button that got pressed.

Also I am wondering if I am somehow able to implement an ActionListener in the Class CustomPanel which can influence the behaviour of the Object which is an instance of my Class Window.

I have kind of the following code:

```
public class Window extends JFrame{
 ArrayList<CustomPanel> aLCustomPanel = new ArrayList();
 JPanel jp = new JPanel();

 public Window() {
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
   aLCustomPanel.add(new CustomPanel());
   //here I could put the code from the 1 edit - see below
   jp.add(aLCustomPanel.get(i));
  }
  this.add(jp);
 }
 public static void main(String args[]){
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    new Window().setVisible(true);
   }
  });
 }
}


class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
 private JButton button;

 public CustomPanel(){
  button = new JButton("button");
  this.add(button);
 }

 public JButton getButton(){
  return this.button;
 }
}
```

my Code is much longer and weirder, so I tried to extract the (for this question) importing things.

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

edit:

for example: I would like to delete the object from the ArrayList, of which the button got pressed.

```
//imagine this comment in above code
aLCustomPanel.get(aLCustomPanel.size()-1).getButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button_IwantToDeleteYou(e); //here I want to remove the panel, containing the button that got pressed from the above ArrayList, which is located in Class Window
            }
        });
```

---

edit2:
added a missing bracket and fixed some mistakes, code should be ok now.

Comment: I still did not understand what object you want to "get". Can you add it as a variable into your code? Maybe like `Object iWantGet = // the Window object`.

Comment: I want the object of type CustomPanel as a return of some function. It is already implemented in my code in form of one of an element. So I want to get that element of ArrayList aLCustomPanel which holds the button that got pressed.
Is that clearer now? Sorry if this is difficult to understand, please give me a hint at which part is not understandable enough.

Comment: *//here I want to remove the Button that got pressed from the above ArrayList, which is located in Class Window* . Arraylist has panels, how can you remove a button from it ?

Comment: First, you need to post a [mcve]. Post the minimal amount of code that I can copy to my computer and then compile it and then run it. Second, your question seems like an example of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to remove the `JButton` after clicking on it?

Comment: sorry guys, you're right about that, I want to remove the panel, containing the button which got pressed. (not the button directly)

I also strongly feel like this is the minimal reproducible example...
I didn't put in all imports I used, but I think they are standart swing parts and known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contained a few "gaps", i.e. missing code, which I filled in, as follows:

1. Added calls to [`JFrame`] methods `setDefaultCloseOperation()` and `pack()` and `setLocationByPlatform()`. I suggest you refer to the *javadoc* for those methods in order to understand what they do.
2. I set a layout manager for `jp` class member variable in your `Window` class.

Yes, you need to register an `ActionListener` with the `JButton` in class `CustomPanel` and that listener should reside in your `Window` class - the one that extends `JFrame`.

Here is my rewrite of your code. Note that I changed the name of class `Window` to `CusPanel` so as to distinguish between your class and `java.awt.Window` class. Not that it makes a difference, I just prefer not to use names of classes from the JDK.

```java
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class CusPanel extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private static final int COUNT = 5;

    private ArrayList<CustomPanel> aLCustomPanel = new ArrayList<>();
    private JPanel jp = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, COUNT));

    public CusPanel() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            aLCustomPanel.add(new CustomPanel(this));
            // here I could put the code from the 1 edit - see below
            jp.add(aLCustomPanel.get(i));
        }
        this.add(jp);
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Object source = actionEvent.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JButton) {
            JButton button = (JButton) source;
            Container parent = button.getParent();
            jp.remove(parent);
            jp.invalidate();
            jp.repaint();
            pack();
//            aLCustomPanel.remove(parent); <- optional
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CusPanel().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
    private JButton button;

    public CustomPanel(ActionListener parent) {
        button = new JButton("button");
        button.addActionListener(parent);
        this.add(button);
    }

    public JButton getButton() {
        return this.button;
    }
}
```

Note that after removing a `CustomPanel`, the GUI components need to be laid out again and the `JFrame` should also be resized accordingly. Hence in the `actionPerformed()` method, I call `invalidate()`, then `repaint()` and then `pack()`. I also think that if you remove a `CustomPanel` from the GUI, you should also remove it from the `ArrayList`, but hey, I still don't understand why you want to do this although I obviously don't know the whole story behind you wanting to do this in the first place.

Of-course, since each button (and each `CustomPanel`) looks exactly the same, you can't really know which button was removed. Again, I assume you see the big picture whereas I don't.

Comment: thanks so much, that's exactly what I was looking for.
sorry for my messy question, I really had difficulty with this.

And the reason I need it is:
I wanted to be able to add new Players to a game and individually be able to remove them again, thats why I need this delete button..